# Difference of lastModifiedDateTime and bodyLastModifiedDateTime in Microsoft Graph todo task apis

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail, microsoft-todo

In Microsoft Graph Todo Task Item documents ([this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/todotasklist-post-tasks?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body)) there are two fields with two different names but with the same description: `lastModifiedDateTime` and `bodyLastModifiedDateTime`.

Anyone knows the difference of these 2 fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the description on [create todoTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/todotasklist-post-tasks?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) is wrong.

If you check [todotask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/todotask?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) resource's properties the `bodyLastModifiedDateTime` has the correct description.

> The date and time when the task body was last modified. By default, it
> is in UTC. You can provide a custom time zone in the request header.
> The property value uses ISO 8601 format and is always in UTC time. For
> example, midnight UTC on Jan 1, 2020 would look like this:
> '2020-01-01T00:00:00Z'.

Comment: Sounds good to see this as a mistake in documents not to me. But another question for me is that why should I fill the field "completedDateTime" in create todo task request. A new created task may not completed yet. Is it correct?